# Stretch div inside a div vertically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the box where the content would always take the 100% height to the bottom(minus the padding), even if it is resized and has small content. I got stuck with ideas… grateful for all suggestions!

Here's a pen as well: https://codepen.io/Dalmat/pen/VOmxzm

```css
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}

.box_bottom {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_top">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="box_bottom">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `height: 100%;` for `.box_bottom`? By my understanding, percentages in CSS are relative to the enclosing element and so setting it to that would be putting it as big as it possibly could be

Comment: Did you try flexBox ? Flex elements are expanding until they can't anymore

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Yeah, even with 100% on the body and html it does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is quite handy for stuff like this. A great article to read is the complete guide to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.box_bottom {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_top">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="box_bottom">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

added min height to `box_bottom`

```css
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}

.box_bottom {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  min-height: 80px
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_top">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="box_bottom">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```